# Problem in angular when I want recover informations of array

Tags: html, angular

I have a problem with my angular code.
This is the code in my animal.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimalService } from "./animal.service";
import { Animal } from "./animal";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-animal',
  templateUrl: './animal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./animal.component.css']
})
export class AnimalComponent implements OnInit {

  private animaux:Array<Animal>;
  private especeAnimalPresente:Array<string>;
  constructor(private animalService: AnimalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recupAllAnimals();
    this.recupEspecePresent();
  }

  recupAllAnimals(){
    this.animalService.getAllAnimaux().subscribe(
      data => {console.log(this.animaux), this.animaux = data, console.log(this.animaux)}
    )
  }

  recupEspecePresent(){
    for (let animal of this.animaux) {
    }
  }
}
```

But I have this error in my console :

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.animaux is undefined"
    recupEspecePresent animal.component.ts:28
    ngOnInit animal.component.ts:18
    Angular 5
    View_AnimalComponent_Host_0 (index):1
    Angular 26
    RxJS 5
    Angular 11
```

I don't understand this problem especially that my array animaux contains many animals. And I display this array in my html code.
This is ma web page :

[image: animals displayed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data for `this.animaux` are fetched asynchronously and there is no guarantee that your `recupEspecePresent` is called after the data are fetched. You should run that function after the fetching is done:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.recupAllAnimals();
}

recupAllAnimals(): void {
  this.animalService.getAllAnimaux().subscribe(data => {
    this.animaux = data;
    this.recupEspecePrsent();
  })
}

recupEspecePresent(): void {
  for (let animal of this.animaux) {
    // do something
  }
}
```